# How to make grep ignore lines without trailing newline character

Tags: grep

I'd like to grep a file for a string, but ignore any matches on lines that do not end with a trailing newline character. In other words, if the file does not end with a newline character, I'd like to ignore the last line of the file.

What is the best way to do this?

I encountered this issue in a python script that calls grep via the `subprocess` module to filter a large text log file before processing. The last line of the file might be mid-write, in which case I don't want to process that line.

Comment: In practice only the last line can miss `\n` so maybe it would be enough to ignore last line?

Comment: What is the best way to conditionally ignore the last line?

Comment: Instead of doing `grep string FILE` do `head -n -1 FILE | grep 'string'`

Comment: That might throw out the last line incorrectly.

Comment: Oh, ok. We can test if the last character in the file is `\n`. What shell do you use?

Comment: do you have to fork out to `grep`? a high level language can probably detect if a line has a newline on it, and do regular expressions on a line, etc

Comment: I use bash as my shell.

Comment: @thrig I fork out for performance reasons, as grep can shrink a 10GB file down to 10MB much faster than python can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is explicitly [defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/grep.html) to ignore newlines, so you can't really use that. `sed` knows internally if the current line (fragment) ends in a newline or not, but I can't see how it could be coerced to reveal that information. `awk` separates records by newlines (`RS`), but doesn't really care if there was one, the default action of `print` is to print a newline (`ORS`) at the end in any case.

So the usual tools don't seem too helpful here.

However, `sed` does know when it's working on the last line, so if you don't mind losing the last intact line in cases where a partial one isn't seen, you could just have `sed` delete what it thinks is the last one. E.g.

```
sed -n -e '$d' -e '/pattern/p'  < somefile                   # or
< somefile sed '$d' | grep ...
```

If that's not an option, then there's always Perl. This should print only the lines that match `/pattern/`, and have a newline at the end:

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern/ && /\n$/'
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the perl solution. It appears to be within a factor of 2 of the speed of grep, which is faster than sed/python/gawk solutions. Is there a simple way to extend it to do the equivalent of `egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3"`?

Comment: @dshin, Perl regexes are pretty much an extension of extended regexes like what `grep -E` uses, so `this|that` works out of the box. (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) and [Perl's docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) for details)

Comment: @dshin, also, since you're aiming for speed, you could try if replacing the second regex with  `... && substr($_, -1, 1) eq "\n"'` would be faster.

Comment: Hm, your original actually is clocking in slightly faster for me, but they are very close.

Comment: @dshin, allright, just goes to show that Perl's regex processing is pretty well optimized

Answer (score 3):

With `gawk` (using EREs similar to `grep -E`):

```
gawk '/pattern/ && RT' file
```

`RT` in `gawk` contains what is matched by `RS` the record separator. With the default value of `RS` (`\n`) that would be `\n` except for a non-delimited last record where `RT` would then be empty.

With `perl` (perl REs similar to `grep -P` where available):

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern/ && /\n\z/'
```

Note that contrary to `gawk` or `grep`, `perl` by default does work on bytes not characters. For instance, it's `.` regexp operator would match on each of the two bytes of a UTF-8-encoded `£`. For it to work on characters as per the locale's definition of characters like for `awk`/`grep`, you'd use:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -ne 'print if /pattern/ && /\n\z/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ "$(tail -c 1 FILE)" = "" ]
then
    printf "Trailing newline found\n"
    # grep whole file
    # grep ....
else
    printf "No trailing newline found\n"
    # ignore last line
    # head -n -1 FILE | grep ...
fi
```

We rely on the following characteristic of command substitution
described in `man bash`:

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any**
>   **trailing newlines deleted.**

Comment: Unfortunately if the file is being written to, there is a potential race condition. The else-case race condition doesn't worry me too much, but the then-case race condition can lead to processing of a partial log line, which is the problem I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I've solved this sort of race condition in similar contexts by first doing a `du -b` to get an exact byte size, and then doing a `tail -c` to only fetch that many bytes. I could do that here.

Comment: On the other hand, in practice skipping the last line *unconditionally* is probably going to be ok for my purposes. So if the simple trick I was hoping for doesn't exist, I might just do that.

Comment: @dshin: OK, I'm glad you found the right solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need speed then using PCRE (or some other possibly faster regex library) from C would allow the use of both a regular expression and a check whether there is a newline. Downsides: new code to maintain and debug, time to re-implementing portions of `grep` or `perl` depending on the complexity of the expression or if features such as `--only-matching` are used.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <pcre.h>
#define MAX_OFFSET 3

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // getline
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linebuflen = 0;
    ssize_t numchars;
    // PCRE
    const char *error;
    int erroffset, rc;
    int offsets[MAX_OFFSET];
    pcre *re;

    if (argc < 2) errx(1, "need regex");
    argv++;
    if ((re = pcre_compile(*argv, 0, &error, &erroffset, NULL)) == NULL)
        err(1, "pcre_compile failed at offset %d: %s", erroffset, error);

    while ((numchars = getline(&line, &linebuflen, stdin)) > 0) {
        if (line[numchars-1] != '\n') break;
        rc = pcre_exec(re, NULL, line, numchars, 0, 0, offsets, MAX_OFFSET);
        if (rc > 0) fwrite(line, numchars, 1, stdout);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is about 49% faster than `perl -ne 'print if /.../ && /\n\z/'`.